# Why can you not include endpoints in monotony intervals for strict monotony?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, definition

Here are the definitions my book gives on monotony:

Definition 1:

> Let $f$ be a function defined on the interval $I$ and for $x_1 \in I$ and $x_2 \in I$, $x_1 < x_2$.
>
> > (1) If $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$, then $f$ is strictly monotonic increasing on $I$.
>
> > (2) If $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$, then $f$ is strictly monotonic decreasing on $I$.
>
> > (3) If $f(x_1) \leq f(x_2)$, then $f$ is monotonic increasing on $I$.
>
> > (4) If $f(x_1) \geq f(x_2)$, then $f$ is strictly monotonic decreasing on $I$.

Definition 2:

> If $f$ is differentiable on $I$ and for all $x \in I$,
>
> > (1) $f'(x) > 0$ holds, then $f$ is strictly monotonic increasing on $I$.
>
> > (2) $f'(x) < 0$ holds, then $f$ is strictly monotonic decreasing on $I$.
>
> > (3) $f'(x) \geq 0$ holds, then $f$ is monotonic increasing on $I$.
>
> > (4) $f'(x) \leq 0$ holds, then $f$ is monotonic decreasing on $I$.

My textbook says that for example for $f(x) = (x-2)^2(x+1)$, $f$ is strictly monotonic decreasing on $(0, 2)$ and monotonic decreasing on $[0, 2]$, but why is this?

After the first definition, $f$ should be strictly monotonic decreasing on $[0, 2]$. If you only looked at the second definition, you could say that it's monotonic decreasing since the first derivative is $0$ at $x = 0$ and $x = 2$, but doesn't that mean that the two definitions don't match?

> How can you justify what my textbook says

Why is this?

Comment: I think all your definitions in 2 say "on $f$" when they should say "on $I$".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Corrected, thanks for noticing.

Comment: That's a problem with textbook (it is also seen in many Indian textbooks). Monotone nature as per definition applies to any interval and not necessarily to open intervals. Your function is strictly decreasing on $[0,2]$.

Comment: I think the source of confusion is due to the fact that sign of derivative on an open interval is sufficient to conclude monotone nature on the corresponding closed interval (provided function is continuous on closed interval).

Comment: Also there is no need to justify things written in textbook. Math textbooks may have errors which are not typos.

Comment: In this case it isn't even technically an error, it's just saying less than it could have. We don't know why the author ignored the endpoints for strictly decreasing. A mistaken application of the definition is possible but not certain. If they had written that the function is monotonic decreasing on $[0,2]$ but not strictly monotonic decreasing on $[0,2]$, **that** would have been an unambiguous error.

Comment: @DavidK It stated that $f$ is strictly monotonic decreasing on $(0, 2)$ and just monotonic decreasing on $[0, 2]$.

Comment: @DavidK Similarly, it stated that $f$ is strictly monotonic increasing for $(-\infty, 0)$ and monotonic increasing for $(-\infty, 0]$. 

So this is just an error caused by a misunderstanding of the definition, it seems.

Comment: Again, **technically** it is not an error as long as both statements are true. If it really said "just monotonic decreasing" then we could infer that it is denying that the function is strictly decreasing, and that would be an error. But you did not write "just" when you quoted the textbook in the question. If you really want to split hairs on this, edit the question so you quote the passage from the textbook word-for-word without inserting or deleting anything, and we can see whether it is wrong or just less thorough than it could have been.

Comment: Also, even though the book might have made **technically** correct statements, the presentation is misleading. After all, it caused you to have doubts about how the definition applied. So I don't mean to defend the book; it really should have said strictly decreasing on $[0,2]$ in order not to mislead students. If you were to write such a thing on the exam I wouldn't be surprised if the grader took off marks for an incomplete answer. You can take marks off the book for the same reason.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks. And is definition 2 correct?

If you have $f(x) = x^3$, that should be strictly monotonic increasing on $\mathbb{R}$, but after definition 2, it's only monotonic increasing.


I guess you could say that the author didn't mean to say "only monotonic increasing" but "atleast monotonic increasing", other than for the intervals, where he actually stated that it's only monotonic decreasing on $[0, 2]$, not strictly.

Comment: The book is just wrong. Moreover, statement (4) in Definition 1 is wrong as you typed it *and* the phrasing (if you copied the book correctly) is very misleading, as it sounds like you only have to check for one particular $x_1<x_2$. Indeed, the hypotheses must hold *for all* $x_1<x_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition 1 is the actual definition. What you call "definition 2" is merely a theorem. There are functions that are not recognized as strictly increasing by the theorem "Definition 2" even though they *are* strictly increasing. Your example function $f(x) = (x-2)^2(x+1)$ is

- strictly increasing on $(-\infty,0]$
- strictly decreasing on $[0,2]$
- strictly increasing on $[2,\infty)$

though the theorem "definition 2" knows this for sure only without the points $0$ and $2$.

(Note also, that $f$ is *not* strictly increasing on $(-\infty,0)\cup(2,\infty)$ even though $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$ in that set)

Comment: Thank you.
Can you think of a reason why my textbook says that it's strictly decreasing on $(0, 2)$ instead of $[0, 2]$ then?

Also, why is $f$ not strictly increasing on $(-\infty, 0)$ or $(2, \infty)$?

Comment: $f$ is not strictly increasing on $(-\infty,0)\cup(2,\infty)$ because $f(-0.1)>f(2.1)$. But $f$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,0]$ as well as any subset thereof